# XML product feed problem with category path

Tags: magento-1.9

I've found a code for exporting products in XML in order to feed price comparison engine. 
Everything works fine except category path. They wanted in Category > Subcategory > ... format. So I used this code to create it

```
//Add Category Name
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $tree = $category->getTreeModel();
    $tree->load();

    $productids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    $categories = array();
    if ($productids)
    {
        foreach ($productids as $productid)
        {
            $category->load($productid);
            $categories[$productid]['name'] = $category->getName();
            $categories[$productid]['path'] = $category->getPath();
        }
        foreach ($productids as $productid)
        {
            $path = explode('/', $categories[$productid]['path']);
            $string = '';
            foreach ($path as $pathId)
            {
                $string.= $categories[$pathId]['name'] . ' > ';
                $cnt++;
            }
            $category_path = substr($string, 34, -3);
        }
    }

    if(count($categoryIds) ){
        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
        $category = $xml->createElement( 'category' );
        $cdatacategory = $xml->createCDATASection($category_path);
        $category->appendChild($cdatacategory);
    }
```

The problem is that for every product in XML file the category path is the same. The result gives the right category id for the product but returns always the last subcategory's path.